# merge data frame rows by string parse

Tags: r, string, text, dataframe, string-concatenation

I'm trying to import into a data frame a conversation with the following structure:

```
conversation<-data.frame(
             uniquerow=c("01/08/2015 2:49:49 pm: Person 1: Hello",
                         "01/08/2015 2:51:49 pm: Person 2: Nice to meet you",
                         "01/08/2015 2:59:19 pm: Person 1: Same here"))
```

This structure would make it relatively easy to parse the date, time, person and message. But there are a few instances where the message carries a newline, and thus the data frame is miss-structured, like such:

```
conversation_errors<-data.frame(
                     uniquerow=c("01/08/2015 2:49:49 pm: Person 1: Hello",
                                 "01/08/2015 2:51:49 pm: Person 2: Nice to meet you",
                                 "01/08/2015 2:59:19 pm: Person 1: Same here, let me tell you a haiku: ",
                                 "lend me your arms,",
                                 "fast as thunderbolts,",
                                 "for a pillow on my journey."))
```

How would you go about merging these instances? Is there any package i'm not aware of?

The desired function would simply recognise the missing structure and "merge" with the preceding row, such that I would get:

```
conversation_fixed<-data.frame(
                    uniquerow=c("01/08/2015 2:49:49 pm: Person 1: Hello",
                                "01/08/2015 2:51:49 pm: Person 2: Nice to meet you",
                                "01/08/2015 2:59:19 pm: Person 1: Same here, let me tell you a haiku: lend me your arms, fast as thunderbolts, for a pillow on my journey."))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are that there needs to be a deterministic way to connect the last 3 rows in data frame `conversation_errors` to Person 1.  Can you explain how this would be known?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen basically, the missing structure... too dirty to have anything more specific, sorry

Comment: You may want to add `stringAsFactors = FALSE` to your data.frame assignment.

Comment: @vaettchen sorry, the reproducible example doesn't have it, but my code does. It is not an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can correctly identify the properly structured rows using the  timestamp (represented below in `properDataRegex`), then this will do it:

```
mydata <- c("01/08/2015 2:49:49 pm: Person 1: Hello",
            "01/08/2015 2:51:49 pm: Person 2: Nice to meet you",
            "01/08/2015 2:59:19 pm: Person 1: Same here, let me tell you a haiku: ",
            "lend me your arms,",
            "fast as thunderbolts,",
            "for a pillow on my journey.",
            "07/07/2015 3:29:00 pm: Person 1: This is not the most efficient method",
            "but it will get the job done.")

properDataRegex <- "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}\\s"
improperDataBool <- !grepl(properDataRegex, mydata)
while (sum(improperDataBool)) {
    mergeWPrevIndex <- which(c(FALSE, !improperDataBool[-length(improperDataBool)]) & 
                             improperDataBool)
    mydata[mergeWPrevIndex - 1] <- 
        paste(mydata[mergeWPrevIndex - 1], mydata[mergeWPrevIndex])
    mydata <- mydata[-mergeWPrevIndex]
    improperDataBool <- !grepl(properDataRegex, mydata)
}

mydata
## [1] "01/08/2015 2:49:49 pm: Person 1: Hello"                                                                                                    
## [2] "01/08/2015 2:51:49 pm: Person 2: Nice to meet you"                                                                                         
## [3] "01/08/2015 2:59:19 pm: Person 1: Same here, let me tell you a haiku:  lend me your arms, fast as thunderbolts, for a pillow on my journey."
## [4] "07/07/2015 3:29:00 pm: Person 1: This is not the most efficient method but it will get the job done."
```

Here, `mydata` is a character vector but of course it's now trivial to make into a data.frame as you had in the question, or to parse it using `read.table()` or `read.fwf()`.

Comment: Had some trouble with the regex, as usual, but works like a charm, thanks!